# How to destroy audio (blown-out clipping effect)

Tags: processing, loudness, clipping

I'm looking for ways to destroy audio without making it sound robotic.
Here is an example video for what I am looking for:

I can use any tools or plugins: Adobe audacity, etc.

Searching for methods only ever returns way to *fix* destroyed audio not actually destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, easy way of doing it is by using the amplify effect in audacity. Just select the audio and increase by a couple of dbs and listen to how it sounds (Remember to enable clipping). If you want it more distorted apply the effect again by different amounts until you get what you want.

Really what you are looking for is distortion. Any digital distortion effect will do for your purpose.

[Here's](https://voicechanger.io/voicemaker/#!/%7B%22effects%22:[%7B%22name%22:%22overdrive%22,%22params%22:%7B%22preBand%22:0.86,%22color%22:18233,%22drive%22:0.85,%22postCut%22:13168%7D%7D],%22version%22:1%7D) a web distortion effect you can use quickly.

Answer (score 0):

That example is simple clipping. You do that by increasing the preamp gain during recording to such an extent that it will overdrive the ADC stage and clip the audio during sampling.

You can also do it in post as well by increasing the inline gain past the clipping point.